# Draw jOrgChart from JSON

Tags: json, charts

Is there any option to do this Org Chart from the JSON ?

Any other option to make charts from json (for html ajax).

Ty so much

Comment: You would have to recursively loop through the Json to build an HTML structure, which Im trying to get right at the moment. The way the UL/LI's are nested make it an interesting task.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its possible. Here I used [taffydb](http://www.taffydb.com/) plugin for querying the json.

You can get full code from [Github](https://github.com/sselvamani22/jOrgChart)